# ionic 4 / Angular - ion-input - custom clear input button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a search input to dispaly a list of items. I want to add a custom clear input button. I.E. I want to replace the existing clearInput in ion-input to use a custom button.

.ts:

```
inputText = '';

clearField() {
    this.inputText = '';
  }
```

.html

```
<div>
  <span (click)="clearField()">CLEAR</span>
   <ion-input (keyup)="filterList($event.target.value)" type="text" [ngModel]="inputText"></ion-input>
</div>
```

this wont work, but the ion-input clearInput does work :/

Answer (score 0):

What if you reference the ion-input?

```
<div>
  <span (click)="refIonInput.clearField()">CLEAR</span>
   <ion-input #refIonInput (keyup)="filterList($event.target.value)" type="text" [ngModel]="inputText"> 
   </ion-input>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, was able to do it with : 

<span (click)="refIonInput.value = '' ">CLEAR</span>